# If a non-religious person is of Jewish heritage, can one wear the Star of David?

Tags: star-of-david

I asked my mother if she can buy me the [Star of David](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_of_David) since my Grandmother is Jewish (as well as my mother) which makes me of Jewish heritage. I dearly respect the religion even though I'm not religious (meaning I don't go to synagogue), however I still believe in God and pray.

Is it ok for me to wear the Star of David since I respect my heritage (and my Grandmother's religion)?

Comment: Dear @Maria, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for the interesting question. You might be interested in learning that Judaism is an "identity" passed down matrilineally (through one's mother). Unlike in Christianity, where a child must be baptized to become a Christian, Judaism is an identity one inherits from one's mother (or chooses when converting to Judaism). That makes you a Jew! Congratulations! As such, there are hardly any cases I can think of in which a Jew wearing a Star of David would be forbidden by Jewish law.

Comment: Heavily related, possibly a duplicate: [Can I still wear my Star of David?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36135/5151)

Comment: @scimonster Definitely a duplicate.

Comment: The Star of David has no religious holiness whatsoever. Numerous Gentiles wear one - at least from what I've seen in the NY area as well as in other areas of the U.S. I can't see any problems with wearing one or not, according to your desires.

Comment: @sabbahillel Maria is Jewish, but the author of the other question was not. Why do you think the questions are the same?

Comment: @Shokhet As pointed out in the comments there, the other OP also is Jewish.

Comment: @Scimonster Ah, I didn't read the other question closely enough.

Comment: @lee Thank you for your answer, it has helped me a great deal.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! I hope you enjoy it :) See also ["Am I Jewish"](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52891/5323). cc @Lee