# Wearing the star of David and wanting to learn more about Judaism

Tags: gentiles, star-of-david

I was wondering if it would be considered rude or disrespectful to wear the star of David considering I was baptized into the catholic church and attend a catholic high school. I am very interested by the jewish religion, and I am wanting to learn more. I have many questions about my faith. To me the star of david is also a symbol of my father's love for Israel. My father spent close to a year in Israel and fell in love with the country, he is not Jewish by any means and was baptized Anglican but does not practice or celebrate the religion. It is a symbol of him for me because of his love and respect for the country.

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36135 (but different enough that I don't think this question should be closed as a duplicate of that one). Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for your sensitivity in asking this question.

Answer (score 3):

Wearing the Star of David, if you are not Jewish, is not considered rude or disrespectful. Although it is certainly confusing to others because it identifies you as a Jew, the same way that wearing a skullcap identifies a man as a Jew, there are many Christians who do wear the Star of David to show their love of Judaism.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for your answer. If you have further support (beyond the fact that many Christians wear David's star) for your claim that it's not considered rude/disrespectful for a non-Jew to wear David's star, you should [edit] that support into your answer post. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site.

Comment: important note though. unlike a yarmulke/kippah (scull-cap) a star of  david has no religious significance. It is a modern symbol which is widely accepted as part of Jewish culture.