# Use of Jewish Decorations and Artifacts by Non-Jews

Tags: gentiles

In another forum I frequent, the question of using some Jewish themed decorations and artifacts (for example Hannukah lights) by Non-Jews came up.  Some felt it was a desecration, some went *meh*.

My thinking was as long as a Non-Jew treats any decorations/artifacts with similar reverence and respect as a Jew would for that same item, there is generally no harm done. For example:

- A few cheap plastic Hannukah lights, meh....
- A Sefer Torah, if it fell into the hands of a Non-Jew please treat with awe and respect that a Jew would, and restore to the Jewish Community as soon as possible.

The basic question: How is a non-Jew expected to treat artifacts of the Jewish religion.  Ranging from items not sacred to the religion like plastic Hannukah decorations, up to a Sefer Torah for example?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66825/170

Comment: I'm trying to understand exactly what you are asking -- is it whether this is halachically sanctioned? Communally acceptable? Is it about guidelines or rules or how we should respond?

Comment: Tried to clarify it a bit at the end, help?