# Star of David necklace

Tags: derech-eretz-manners, jewelry, star-of-david

My mother went to Israel and just came back. She's Catholic and went to Israel to see the Holy Land. She came back and gave me a star of David. She said it was blessed. I am Catholic myself and wearing it simply because she says it's blessed. Is it wrong to wear it? Would people get offended?

Comment: the question's conditions are slightly different but the answers might help http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36135/can-i-still-wear-my-star-of-david

Comment: Is this off topic in the same way a request for psak is off topic?

Answer (score 1):

No one should be offended by you choosing to wear a necklace.

It's hard to say who will be offended by what as t here is always some fool that's looking to be offended by something.

That being said the star of David is not a religious symbol but a relatively new cultural symbol.